# How to use a Django Patch within my Heroku environment?

Tags: django, heroku, patch

So I've learnt how to apply a Django patch within my local environment:

```
sudo patch -p2 < ~/Downloads/html5-input-types-take3.patch
```

I'm struggling to find any information about how to do this on my Heroku environment though. Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can create a kind of 'patch' aplication in your project and put django/forms/fields.py and django/forms/widgets.py patched files into this app. Then use this 'patch' modules instead django modules. It is only a start point. As you know, you can not change files in heroku environment (well, you can change files for your instance, but each instance has a clone copy or original environment).

Comment: If the name of your patch is accurate, you could also consider a work-around. You can get HTML5 input types by [over-riding the widget for form fields](http://www.thepiepers.net/blog/bryan-pieper/2011/01/html5-django-form-inputs/) or using something like [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post your modified version of Django to a Git repo (such as one on GitHub), and then specify in `requirements.txt` to pull Django from that repo instead of PyPI.